# Writing an escaped/unescaped Observable in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have an issue where I want to store everything as quoted strings and display everything unquoted while in the form. My first solution was to just create two extra bindingHandlers to do this one for value and one for text.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.escapedValue = {
    init : function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element),
            contentObservable = valueAccessor(),
            currentTxt = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(contentObservable);

        if (currentTxt) {
            $element.val(unescape(currentTxt));
        }

        $element.change(function (e) {
            contentObservable(escape($element.val()));
        });
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.escapedText = {
    init : function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element),
            contentObservable = valueAccessor(),
            currentTxt = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(contentObservable);

        if (currentTxt) {
            $element.text(unescape(currentTxt));
        }

        contentObservable.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            $element.text(unescape(newValue));
        });
    }
};
```

However that gave me two issues 1) I do not get live updating anymore after key down 2) When I do some validation on the values for example character length it checks the length of the quoted string.

How can I write something like a ko.escapedObservable() or ko.subscribable.fn.escaped()

I have gotten closer but cant seem to get the saving correct. So now it displays properly and does the comparison properly but when I goto save it the values are still unescped

```
ko.escapedObservable = function (initialValue) {
    var observableVal = ko.observable(initialValue),

    result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return unescape(observableVal());
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            return observableVal(escape(newValue));
        }
    });

    this.toJSON = function () {
        return escape(observableVal());
    };

    return result;
};
```

====EDIT====
Solution using two observables 
// Escape and Unescape a text value

```
ko.escapedObservable = function (initialValue) {
    var observableVal = ko.observable(initialValue),

    result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return observableVal();
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            observableVal(newValue);
        }
    });

    result.unescaped = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return unescape(observableVal());
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            observableVal(escape(newValue));
        }
    });

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ko.escapedObservable = function (initialValue) {
    var observableVal = ko.observable(initialValue),

    result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return observableVal();
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            observableVal(newValue);
        }
    });

    result.unescaped = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return unescape(observableVal());
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            observableVal(escape(newValue));
        }
    });

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you are asking. However, I believe you really just need a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html): [**[Example]**](http://jsfiddle.net/GqvEY/)

```
function viewModel() {
    this.test = ko.observable('\"Something\"');

    this.escapedTest = ko.computed(function () {
        return escape(this.test());
    }, this);

    this.unescapedTest = ko.computed(function () {
        return unescape(this.escapedTest());
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: yea that is great for 1 field but imagine having 20,30, or an unknown amount of those type of properties it would be a lot of code to do this everywhere. I want to somehow do this globally across any knockout observable that I might want to call escapedObservable() or something.